# Application deployed in weblogic instance is running Slow

Tags: multithreading, deployment, oracle-adf, weblogic12c

My application deployed in Weblogic instance is getting too slow sometimes. At that time, it's hitting the error related to Stuck Thread Time in Managed server log. Initially, when I noticed this, I did some research and increased the value of Max Stuck Thread Time to 800 seconds in place of 600 seconds. But, this didn't fix the issue. I got the following error again.

```
WatchRule: (SEVERITY = 'Error') AND ((MSGID = 'WL-000337') OR (MSGID = 'BEA-000337'))
WatchData: MESSAGE = [STUCK] ExecuteThread: '58' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' has been busy for "812" seconds working on the request "Http Request Information: weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl@42f38088[POST /****/faces/index.jsf]
", which is more than the configured time (StuckThreadMaxTime) of "800" seconds in "server-failure-trigger". Stack trace:
  oracle.jbo.pcoll.PCollNode.objectAt(PCollNode.java:1753)
  oracle.jbo.pcoll.PCollNode.objectAt(PCollNode.java:1753)
  oracle.jbo.pcoll.PCollection.elementAt(PCollection.java:839)
  oracle.jbo.server.QueryCollection.get(QueryCollection.java:2556)
  oracle.jbo.server.ViewRowSetImpl.getRow(ViewRowSetImpl.java:5540)
  oracle.jbo.server.ViewRowSetIteratorImpl.getRangeIndexOf(ViewRowSetIteratorImpl.java:1179)
  oracle.jbo.server.ViewRowSetIteratorImpl.notifyRowUpdated(ViewRowSetIteratorImpl.java:3491)


We are using
ADF 12c for application development
Weblogic Version: 12.2.1 in windows server
Database : Oracle 11g
Jdk version : 1.8-65
```

Can anyone please advise me on the reason and possible solution for this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the stuck threads time will not resolve your issue. From the stack trace it looks like your application may be reading some file. There can be different reason for slowness

1) May be the file which you are reading is very large
2) May be slow network
3) May be IO latency

If possible you can introduce some debugging messages in your application. This will provide the details on the process which your application is running.
If you are running your application on linux/unix environment then you can monitor process activity inside the /var/proc directory

Comment: Yes, As you mentioned increasing stuck threads time didn't resolve our issue.  We are running our weblogic server in windows machine and we don't have any network issues. Also, we have notification pushing feature in our application, its working in real time and using long polling method. We suspect that this feature is the culprit for this issue, but we are not sure about this. Is there any way out to find the actual reason without disabling this notification feature?                                                                                       Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ofcourse...it is possible to identify the root cause. My suggestion is to start active monitoring of weblogic via JMX. Enable JMX on  weblogic and you can use Visual VM/JMC for monitoring purpose. Take a snap shot of weblogic when performance is ok and another snapshot when performance is not ok. Do a comparison of snap shot. Look at the methods carefully in the thread dumps of both the snap shots

Comment: Also, take diagnostic images of weblogic i.e. image when performance is ok v/s when performance is not ok